# How to implement chrome's "merge tabs and apps" feature in an android application?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, android-activity

I want a functionality where new documents open up as separate activities but are accessible on press of a button instead of searching for them in Recents app switcher of Android.

I am able to use documentLaunchMode='always' and FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK flag to show all the launched activities in the Recents switcher.
[image: Tab switcher in Chrome Android]